# Better way to handle n number of if-else if in java

Tags: java, if-statement, optimization, conditional-statements

I was wondering if there is any better way to handle n no. of if/else-if block in Java.

I have a situation where I need to print different values based on n no. of if/else-if/conditions blocks like

```
if(p==1 && q==r)
  System.out.println("Condition 1");
else if(r==p && q==9)
  System.out.println("Condition 2");
else if(z==1 && s==r)
  System.out.println("Condition 3");
else if(p==1 || x==r && y==7)
  System.out.println("Condition 4");
else if(q==z && y==r || p==4)
  System.out.println("Condition 5");
else if(x==z && r==5 || z==30)
  System.out.println("Condition 6");
else if(s==1 || q==x)
  System.out.println("Condition 7");
else if(r==14 || q==r++ || z==y)
  System.out.println("Condition 8");
else if(q==18 && s==r || p==90)
  System.out.println("Condition 9");
else if(y==19 || q==89)
  System.out.println("Condition 10");
...
```

Is there any other way to handle it instead of putting multiple if/else if statements so that if later on any new condition come, it will be easy to handle it.

Comment: It’s hard to give general answers. Maybe you want to tell more about the situation where you encountered this requirement and someone may be able to suggest something from a higher point of view.

Comment: A common example for this situation is a salesman problem where he needs to decide to going to which city everyday based on several factors like weather, distance, time, business priority, no. of  target customers to meet, personal priorities, next day planned visit etc.

Comment: It’s a still a bit vague. For the salesman, I imagine that I would use a data structure describing each possible city (for example with distance, no. of target customers, weather sensiblity, date of last visit and list of customers with priorities). And then a method or even a strategy class to pick the best city from the data and return it to me.

Comment: I appreciate the accept ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer here: don't do that.

In good OO design, you solve this problem in very different ways; for example by using polymorphism. You actually want to **avoid** having many different sources of information, to then make decisions on that.

In your case; I would be thinking towards FSMs and the [state pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) for example.

What I mean is: your code is showing a certain "approach" towards solving a problem. And as long as you keep that approach as is, you are *only* talking about finding ways to express your solution in the "least ugly" way.

Instead, you should step back and look into approaches that can be expressed in "really beautiful" ways.

Thus: there is no "simple" direct answer to your question. You have to step back and have a close look at the requirements you want to fulfill; to then design a better, "more OO" solution to that.

The minimal thing here: you could start by declaring an enum like:

```
public enum Condition {
  A, B, C, ...
```

and then you would have some factory method that **hides** all those statements; like:

```
Condition currentCondition = determineCondition(p, q, r, z);
switch(currentCondition) {
  case A:
```

Meaning: you want to at least "centralize" that knowledge somewhere to avoid code duplication. But again; that is just like putting some new color on an old, rusty car. It helps for the moment, but doesn't really improve things.

Regarding your comments: yes, the switch is only marginally "better" than if elses. But as you said: you can't make too many chances, so at least you want to have exactly **one** piece of code that determines state.

But in the end: I think you are approaching this on a wrong level. You are probably dealing with some kind of **complicated** business logic; and you want to solve that on a low level like this. But *nothing* you do on such a level will lead to a robust, long-term maintainable solution. Probably the real solution is to step back and look into using some kind of [workflow engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workflow_engine).

Comment: Nice option, but when you still need a switch, your separation of concerns is still not perfect. The calling code should not know about all different options, because then you need to adjust the code here when you get a new option.

Comment: That is why I call that a "minimal thing"; and point out that it only adds value on the surface, too ;-)

Comment: Good option however again determineCondition() method will be having again the multiple if/else-if

Comment: @ernitingoel Exactly. That is why I am pointing out that you have to do more than just refactor the surface.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a Condition (interface or superclass) which accepts all your variables:

```
public interface Condition {
    boolean isConditionMet(int p, int q, int r, int s, int x, int y, int z);
    void performAction();
}
```

For each single Condition you can override/implement a boolean method isConditionMet().

```
public class C1 implements Condition {
    public boolean isConditionMet(int p, int q, int r, int s, int x, int y, int z) {
        return p == 1 && q == r;
    }
    public void performAction() {
        System.out.println("Condition 1");
    }
}
```

Then you can put all conditions in a collection, and for each Condition you have you can ask:

```
if (condition.isConditionMet())
    condition.performAction();
```

Now each Condition object **itself** is responsible for **when** it should act, and **what** it should do then. A perfect separation of concerns.

Comment: Helpful; but **far** from perfect. What if the number of arguments changes ... then you have to update all of them. Then: **unused** parameters are "bad style"; and a lot of people regard "more than 2, max 3" parameters as "bad style, too. So, yes helpful; but only on the surface.

Comment: What if I have 100 conditions like that, I will be ending up having 100 different classes.

Comment: If you have 100 conditions, you will get 100 classes. Is that a problem? If so, you can write lambda's to get rid of that, but still I don't see a problem. The concern is separated, and when you write a new interface implementation, most of the code gets generated so you're done in no time. If you have eventually a huge amount of ints which have to be checked and every int which has to be checked is all the time different, I think there is a problem in your data model elsewhere...

Comment: @ernitingoel If you have 100 conditions; any attempt to solve it this way will lead into un-maintainable horror spaghetti code sooner or later (rather soon). That is why I suggest that you step back and look into *other*; more OO ways of solving your requirements. And yes, if you have a complicated state machine, then things get complicated. But you are still better of separating them nicely compared to pushing them into gigantic if/else cascades.

Comment: Funny, someone suggesting a switch in the code says my idea is far from perfect. I.m.h.o. any switch in the code is wrong, as calling code needs to know about what happens with objects it uses. That is never good.

Comment: It's not about generating code, it's about maintaining it also, having n no. of classes for n conditions is not a good option. int is an example here, I have a situation also where I need to compare strings/objects also. It's an enhancement in existing project, I just can't change the data model on my wish.

Comment: If you have over 100 conditions and they change too often too.... I would have found another job because that software will never be finished. And certainly not in a good software writing way.

Answer (score 1):

*Downvote bait*

When you say "if any new condition come" do you mean you are willing to modify the code if a new condition comes, or must the code adapt without being modified? If the former, I think you've done it the best way. (Though, I would add an `if (false){}` at the top, so all the real cases look the same, making it easy to rearrange them.) If the latter, then a table-driven approach is needed. Performance is not an issue if every case has a print statement. If you do care about performance, then put the most common cases first.

If you care even more about performance, have a tree of if-statements, rather than a ladder. So, for example, have something like this, so you're not repeatedly asking the same sub-question:

```
if (p == 1){
    .. all the cases where p is 1
} else {
    .. all the other cases
}
```

There may be other OO-related ways to write this, but none of them will be faster or easier to modify than this.