# How can I optimize the following if else?

Tags: java, if-statement

I have the following if else block.

```java
if (result.first && result.last) {
    output= "both present"
} else if (!result.first && result.last) {
    output= "last present"
} else if (result.first && !result.last) {
    output= "first present"
} else {
    output = "none present"
}
```

The code looks clumsy. Is there any way I can optimize it.

Comment: This might be interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437655/better-way-to-handle-n-number-of-if-else-if-in-java. ENums are a great way to make your code very easy to  read and understand.

Comment: It would be nice if you made your code compile first.

Comment: One possibility would be to move the most probable condition resulting in true to the top. Short circuiting & is another option.

Comment: You still have to have 4 strings ("both", "last", "first", "none"), so I guess this `if` is the shortest.

Comment: What's wrong with it (other than it wont compile). It's effective and fast. If you don't like how it looks then hide it in a method somewhere: `String output = whatIsResult(result.first, result.last);`.

Answer (score 2):

Just a fancy way is to use a ternary operator. This is no different than using an if-cascade though, but is a single assignment (handy if `output` is `final`, though not strictly necessary even in this case).

```
output = 
  result.first 
    ? (result.last ? "both present" : "first present")
    : (result.last ? "last present" : "none present");
```

Since there are 4 possible outcomes, it's impossible to reduce it below `log_2(4) == 2` nested conditions.

You could also use a predefined lookup map.

Answer (score 1):

```java
if (result.first && result.last){
   output= "both present"
} else if (result.last) {
   output= "last present"
} else if (result.first) {
   output= "first present"
} else {
   output = "none present"
}
```

Also, if you can, you might put the logic into the "result", then you don't have to "get" things that belong to the result. You might even replace the if/else with polymorphism if you push the logic up far enough.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking both in single condition, use nested `if` statements:

```
if (result.first) {
    if (result.last) {
        output = "both present";
    } else {
        output = "first present";
    }
} else {
    if (result.last) {
        output = "last present";
    } else {
        output = "none present";
    }
}
```

That easily leads to using ternary conditional operator:

```
if (result.first) {
    output = (result.last ? "both present" : "first present");
} else {
    output = (result.last ? "last present" : "none present");
}
```

Which can also be nested:

```
output = (result.first ? (result.last ? "both present" : "first present")
                       : (result.last ? "last present" : "none present"));
```

If there were many booleans to check, deeply nesting can become cumbersome, so you could alternatively use bit-masking:

```
private static final String[] OUTPUTS = { "none present", "first present",
                                          "last present", "both present" };
```

```
output = OUTPUTS[(result.first ? 1 : 0) + (result.last ? 2 : 0)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
output = "none present"
if (result.first){
   output= "first present"
   if(result.last){
      output= "both present"
    }
} else if (result.last) {
output= "last present"
}
```

Comment: my bad. I missed it.

Comment: But you could assign a value to `output` 3 times with this solution, that’s a drawback

Comment: that's true, but I believe that comparison has more (albeit unnoticeable) cost on the system.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach to deal with statements like that, lets assume that `result` is an object and has two primitive boolean members (bear in mind, that in "big" boolean might be a null) `first` and `last` (**with getter methods**)

```java
public class Result {

  private boolean first;
  private boolean last;

//getters, constructor etc

}
```

Let's wrap conditions in `Predicate` and put it into map where key is predicate and value is an expected value:

```java
private final static Predicate<Result> = RESULT_1-> result.getFirst() && result.getLast();
private final static Predicate<Result> = RESULT_2 -> !result.getFirst() && result.getLast();
private final static Predicate<Result> = RESULT_3 -> result.getFirst() && !result.getLast();

private final static DEFAULT_VALUE = "none present";

private final static Map<Predicate<Result>, String> RESULT_MAP = Map.of(
RESULT_1, "both present",
RESULT_2, "last present",
RESULT_3, "first presnt");
```

Then you can use it in this way:

```java
String output = map.entrySet().stream().filter(predicate -> predicate.getKey().test(resultToTest))
        .findFirst()
        .map(Entry::getValue).orElse(DEFAULT_VALUE);
```

Ofcourse give those variables meanigfull names, do some extraction etc. In this approach when you have to add new condition to code, you just add new predicate to map, and that's all. In case small as yours, you don't have to write flexiable code as I showed, but in more complicated issues this approach is sutiable.