# Is there a way to simplify/improve this if else?

Tags: java, if-statement, java-11

Newbie here, using Java 11 and trying to figure out if there is a better way to write the below code:

```
if(code == 1){
    return (ClassName.static_list1.contains(string_object));
}else if(code == 2){
    return (ClassName.static_list2.contains(string_object));
}else if(code == 3){
    return (ClassName.static_list3.contains(string_object));
}else if(code == 4){
    return (ClassName.static_list4.contains(string_object));
}else{
    return false;
}
```

The method returns a boolean value and those lists are coming from a constant class. Please let me know if it can be improved in anyway.

Comment: Why you are not use switch......case?

Comment: You could use a `Map<Integer, List<String>>` and index it by `code`. The next refactoring could then be to replace `int code` with an `Enum`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better way to handle n number of if-else if in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437655/better-way-to-handle-n-number-of-if-else-if-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

I would propose two orthogonal refactorings.

First, I propose to replace `int code` with an `enum Code`, so we have values with semantic names.

Second, I propose to use a `Map<Code, List<String>>`, which we can then access with a value of `Code`. If we want only to use this optimization, we can use a `Map<Integer, List<String>>` instead.

Taking this all together, a solution might look like this:

```
public enum Code {
  FOO, BAR
}
```

---

```
Map<Code, List<String>> map = ...;

boolean contains(Code code, String stringObject) {
  return map.getOrDefault(code, List.of()).contains(stringObject);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extract a method, which selects the list (or collection) on which you want to call `contains`. This can be implemented with a switch/case, an array, or a `Map<Integer, List<String>>`. The fallback is returning an empty collection (which never contains anything, so returns false).

```
static List<String> listByCode(final int code) {
  switch (code) {
    case 1: return ClassName.static_list1;
    case 2: return ClassName.static_list2;
    case 3: return ClassName.static_list3;
    case 4: return ClassName.static_list4;
    default: return Collections.emptyList();
  }
}

// call site (your existing code):
return listByCode(code).contains(string_object);
```

Alternative solutions using an array:

```
private static List<String>[] lists = {
  ClassName.static_list1,
  ClassName.static_list2,
  ClassName.static_list3,
  ClassName.static_list4
}

static List<String> listByCode(final int code) {
  return code > 0 && code < lists.length
      ? lists[code - 1]
      : Collections.emptyList();
  // alternatively: don't check and just throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
}
```

… and with a Map:

```
private static Map<Integer, List<String>> listsByCode = Map.of(
    1, ClassName.static_list1,
    2, ClassName.static_list2,
    3, ClassName.static_list3,
    4, ClassName.static_list4
);

static List<String> listByCode(final int code) {
  return listsByCode.getOrDefault(code, Collections.emptyList());
}
```

Note that the array- and map-based solutions do not allow you to replace the list references in your class, whereas the switch-based solution does. But maybe you don't need to have separate references and the array/map can be the canononical way to access those lists.

Comment: Ooo, I like the use of Collections.emptyList() here. Makes it very concise. updooty

Comment: I also thought about the array indexing, though OP will have to either change the code he uses to fit the indexes or -1 to zero index it

Comment: Ah yes, that should have been zero-indexed all along. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 2):

## Switch expressions

Using [switch expression](https://openjdk.org/jeps/361), available since Java 14:

```java
return switch (code) {
    case 1 -> ClassName.staticList1.contains(stringObject);
    case 2 -> ClassName.staticList2.contains(stringObject);
    case 3 -> ClassName.staticList3.contains(stringObject);
    case 4 -> ClassName.staticList4.contains(stringObject);
    default -> false;
};
```

The call to `contains()` can be factored out of the switch, but not sure if that is worth it (adding an empty dummy list for the `default` case, maybe less *clean*.)

BTW Java Naming convention `string_object`->`stringObject`, `static_list1`->`staticList1`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using a switch-statement (as mentioned), you should also consider making a method that returns just the list, based on the passed in code. Your current code duplicates that "contains(string_object)"-statments onto every branch. The way I would handle this, is the following (pseudo-code):

```
var list = ClassName.getList(code); // implement static "getList" with a switch-statement
if (list)
    return list.contains(string_object);
else
    return false;
```

Comment: java does not have truthy/falsy; returning `null` for not found when semantically you treat 'not found' identically to 'empty list' is weird: Just define `getList()` to return an empty list for unknown codes. _or_ throw an exception on unknown codes, if even asking for the list of an unknown code is in itself  bizarre (which hints that `code` should be an enum and not an int if that is the case). Either way, returning `null` is likely to be by a considerable margin the worst option here.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Java-specifics aside (I mentioned it was pseudo-code), my solution is meant for getList to be used in a case where a difference between "empty name-list" and "unknown code" is present, without the latter being an error. All things you mention are valid, or potentially better options depending on the case, but calling returning null as "worst by  a margin" is utter nonesense.

Answer (score 0):

this is the best way in my opinion:

```
static List<String> searchByCode(final int code) {
  switch (code) {
    case 1: 
        return ClassName.static_list1;
    case 2: 
        return ClassName.static_list2;
    case 3: 
        return ClassName.static_list3;
    case 4: 
        return ClassName.static_list4;
    default: 
        return Collections.emptyList();
  }
}

return searchByCode(code).contains(string_object);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it like this.  Just use a map and put the lists in that.

```
public class ClassName {
    static List<String> static_list1 = List.of("A", "B");
    static List<String> static_list2 = List.of("C", "D");
    static List<String> static_list3 = List.of("E", "F");
    static List<String> static_list4 = List.of("G", "H");
    static Map<Integer, List<String>> map = Map.of(1, ClassName.static_list1, 2,
            ClassName.static_list2, 3, ClassName.static_list3, 4,
            ClassName.static_list4);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(contains(10,"A"));
        System.out.println(contains(1,"A"));
        System.out.println(contains(1,"C"));
        System.out.println(contains(2,"D"));
        System.out.println(contains(3,"A"));
    }
// Unless the code is in the map and the object is 
// in the list, false will be returned.

    public static boolean contains(int code, String object) {
        return map.containsKey(code) && map.get(code).contains(object);
    }

}
```

prints

```
false
true
false
true
false
```